# Insert webproperties via api whitelisted for project but still not working

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I have requested beta access to google analytics api (in order to create webproperties via api) for a project and I received the confirmation email that the project has been whitelisted to use those resources.

I have created a service account and added the email of that service account as a user of a google analytics account where I would like to create webproperties. Then I get the token with proper scopes for google analytics (I put them all for testing, just in case:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly"
```

I am able to call the webproperties list method without any issue but when I try to insert a new webproperty I do always receive: Error **403: Your project does not have access to this feature., insufficientPermissions.**

Now it is a few days that I should have got access, but I could not manage to use those beta resources.

thanks a lot for your help

kind regards,

R

Comment: Have you tried not including the analytics.readonly permission? It's possible that is limiting write access for your request.

Comment: Double check that you are using the same project you requested be whitelisted. If all else fails request again and double check the project number before submitting.